# Visual Studio 2017 - could not deduce template argument (with variadic templates)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, variadic-templates, c++17

The following code compiles and works fine in gcc and clang, but fails to compile in Visual Studio 2017.7 (x86-64):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <template <typename...> class>
struct isVector : public std::false_type
{ };

template <>
struct isVector<std::vector> : public std::true_type
{ };

// Other isVector specializations (for QVector<T>, etc...)
// ...


// A function accepting vector<vector<double>>
template <
    template<typename ...> class V1,
    template<typename ...> class V2 >
auto loadData(V1<V2<double>> & v, std::string fn)
-> std::enable_if_t<isVector<V1>::value && isVector<V2>::value>
{
    std::cout << "- vector of vector version, " << fn << std::endl;
}

// A function accepting vector<double>
template <
    template<typename ...> class V >
auto loadData(V<double> & v, std::string fn)
-> std::enable_if_t<isVector<V>::value>
{
    std::cout << "- vector version, " << fn << std::endl;

    V<V<double>> vv({ v });

    loadData(vv, fn);
}

// Other loadData() function specializations and overloads
// ...


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vd;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vvd;

    loadData(vd, "case  1");
    loadData(vvd, "case  2");

    return 0;
}
```

This is the error message:

```
<source>(50): error C2672: 'loadData': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(50): error C2784: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V<double> &,std::string)': could not deduce template argument for 'V<double> &' from 'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
<source>(31): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(50): error C2782: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V<double> &,std::string)': template parameter 'V' is ambiguous
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
<source>(31): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(50): note: could be 'std::_Vector_alloc'
<source>(50): note: or       'std::vector'
<source>(50): error C2784: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V1<V2<double>> &,std::string)': could not deduce template argument for 'V1<V2<double>> &' from 'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
<source>(22): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(50): error C2782: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V1<V2<double>> &,std::string)': template parameter 'V1' is ambiguous
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
<source>(22): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(50): note: could be 'std::_Vector_alloc'
<source>(50): note: or       'std::vector'
<source>(51): error C2672: 'loadData': no matching overloaded function found
<source>(51): error C2784: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V<double> &,std::string)': could not deduce template argument for 'V<double> &' from 'std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
<source>(31): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(51): error C2782: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V<double> &,std::string)': template parameter 'V' is ambiguous
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
<source>(31): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(51): note: could be 'std::_Vector_alloc'
<source>(51): note: or       'std::vector'
<source>(51): error C2784: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V1<V2<double>> &,std::string)': could not deduce template argument for 'V1<V2<double>> &' from 'std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
        and
        [
            _Ty=double
        ]
<source>(22): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(51): error C2782: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type loadData(V1<V2<double>> &,std::string)': template parameter 'V2' is ambiguous
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
<source>(22): note: see declaration of 'loadData'
<source>(51): note: could be 'std::_Vector_alloc'
<source>(51): note: or       'std::vector'
```

Is this a VS or a code bug? Any suggestions on how to fix it?
I did try compiling with `/permissive-` and `/std:latest`, didn't make a difference.

The original code was suggested in the accepted answer here:
[A function template that accepts both std::vector and QVector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50231612/a-function-template-that-accepts-both-stdvector-and-qvector)

Compiler explorer link: https://godbolt.org/g/by7nBM

Thanks!

Comment: Shorter example: https://godbolt.org/g/U28P9R

Comment: @aschepler Yeah, looks like MSVC doesn't like defaulted template arguments on their template template parameters...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a VS or a code bug?

I bet a "D'oh!" that is a VS bug.

See the second message error

```
<source>(50): error C2784: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type
              loadData(V<double> &,std::string)': could not deduce
              template argument for 'V<double> &' from
              'std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
    with
    [
        _Ty=void
    ]
    and
    [
        _Ty=double
    ]
```

The same `_Ty` identifier is used for two **differents** defaults template parameters:

One

```
enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type
// .............^^^ (void)
```

Two

```
std::vector<double,std::allocator<_Ty>>`
// ...............................^^^ (double)
```

They should be different identifiers.

Suggestion: try explicating the first one

```
-> std::enable_if_t<isVector<V>::value, void>
// .....................................^^^^
```

Comment: This is not usually a problem. The compiler can tell them apart internally, but when it prints them out in error messages, they happen to have the same name.

Comment: Still the same error, unfortunately (checked with compiler explorer).
Looks like a compiler error as well (not just stdlib).

Answer (score 0):

I too have bumped into this nasty little bug. I think it's a bug as well. The following code used to work under previous versions:

```
namespace Catch {
    template<typename Ty_, typename... Args_>
    std::string Tags(Ty_ x, Args_... others) {
        return Tags(x) + Tags(others...);
    }
}
```

And so on, and would be useful as follows:

```
TEST_CASE("my test case", Catch::Tags("one", "two", "fred", "red")) {
    // ...
}
```

With [`Catch2`](http://github.com/catchorg/Catch2), not sure if you need to append an `.c_str()` on that; at least in `Catch`, I think that was necessary. Perhaps not so much any more.

I did this in an effort to keep from having to trip up over tag syntax, and I could simply focus on the tags themselves and leave the boilerplate syntax for the variadic functions.

However... Now I've run afoul of this compiler bug.

Any idea if there is a [patch coming in response](http://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/286127/vs2017-wont-compile-valid-code-defaulted-arguments.html)?