# How to overcome the MSVC bug of failing deduction of template argument of pointer to member method?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++14, compiler-bug

Below is a minimal code which [compiles in g++](http://ideone.com/fkuvHa), but gives [error in MSVC](https://rextester.com/MERJ37788):

```
template<typename Type,
         typename Return,  // <--- error: this is not deduced
         typename Container,
         typename Parameter>
Container
StringTo (Type&& copy,
          const char tokens[],
          Return (Container::*Insert) (const Parameter&))
{
  static_assert(not std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  Container container;
  return container;
}

template<typename Type>
auto
StringToVector (Type&& copy,
                const char tokens[])
{
  static_assert(not std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  return StringTo(std::move(copy), tokens, &std::vector<Type>::push_back); // <--- here
}

int main()
{
  auto v = StringToVector(std::string("hello world"), " ");
}
```

As per this post, it's a bug in MSVC which is not yet fixed: [Visual Studio 2017 - could not deduce template argument (with variadic templates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134948/visual-studio-2017-could-not-deduce-template-argument-with-variadic-templates)

**Question**: What is the workaround to fix it for this specific case?

---

**Update**: This bug isn't fixable, & I am open to changing of design/interface. You are welcome to post it as an answer. Will accept the best one.

Comment: Do you really need `typename Return, 
         typename Container,
         typename Parameter`?  You could just have `typename ContainerFunc` or `typename MemberFunc`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe attempting to take function pointers to `std` library functions is not sanctioned. They might be overloaded, they might be functor objects, it's all implementation detail. The rule of thumb for compatibility with the standard library is _"If it's a function, call it. If it's a type, instantiate it"_. Can you remodel this code to work with a lambda instead?

Comment: @MaxLanghof In this case it has to be overloaded as `push_back` has lvalue and rvalue overloads

Comment: You could do `return StringTo(std::move(copy), tokens, (void (std::vector<Type>::*)(const Type&))&std::vector<Type>::push_back);` but I don't know if that's what you were going for. Also, there's no variadic template in your case, so I doubt this is related to the other question you linked

Comment: @Nathan, I am ok to change design. Post your proposed solution.

Comment: Return types has seen a lot of issues with MSVC going back and forth between different compiler versions so this is no surprise what so ever - but what do you mean by work around exactly ? writing the parameters explicit works well enough - is that a usable work around ? (perhaps deduce them yourself)

Comment: @Max, that's a good point. Plz post a possible solution with any proposed design.

Comment: @iammilind Are you adding strings to the vector, or are you adding the characters from the string into the vector?  The way you use `&std::vector<Type>::push_back` makes me thing the former, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: @Nathan, adding strings to vector. Probably this stripped down version is not a good indicator. Assume it to be any method, which can insert string/value to a container.

Comment: It just occurred to me, maybe what you really are looking is `back_inserter` ? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: are you compiling with `/permissive-` if not you're getting the old style MSVC template behavior

Comment: @Mgetz, yes I am compiling with `/permissive-` flag. Is that the root cause? This flag was added originally, to avoid some other issues related to MSVC.

Comment: @iammilind it eliminates a whole host of MSVC specific template bugs, that said it doesn't guarantee perfect conformance (yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding the container type you want to the template parameter list of `StringTo` and then taking the function as a generic type allows you to use a lambda in `StringToVector` to forward to the correct member function.  That would look like

```
template<typename Container,
         typename Type,
         typename Func>
Container
StringTo (Type&& copy,
          const char tokens[],
          Func func)
{
  static_assert(not std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  Container container;
  func(container, std::move(copy));
  return container;
}

template<typename Type>
auto
StringToVector (Type&& copy,
                const char tokens[])
{
  static_assert(not std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  return StringTo<std::vector<Type>>(std::move(copy), tokens, [](auto& cont, auto&& val){ cont.push_back(std::move(val)); } ); // <--- here
}

int main()
{
  auto v = StringToVector(std::string("hello world"), " ");
}
```

And you can see it working on Rextester here: https://rextester.com/BLSS95194

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's useful for general purpose. The workaround is posted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58387498/514235).

Answer (score 1):

A more *lean* design might just do:

```
template<typename Type>
auto
StringToVector (Type&& copy,
                const char tokens[])//what are we going to use this for ?
{
  return std::vector{ copy };
}
```

[Try it yourself on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P9W4XT)

Would that be a usable work-around ?

---

Another approach could be to use a type based customization design from the get-go
instead (example using `std::back_insert_iterator`)

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename Container,
         typename Inserter,
         typename Type
         >
Container
StringTo (Type&& copy,
          const char tokens[])
{
  static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  Container container;
  *Inserter(container) = copy;
  return container;
}

template<typename Type>
auto
StringToVector (Type&& copy,
                const char tokens[])
{
  static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<Type>::value, "Must be rvalue.");
  return StringTo<std::vector<Type>, std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<Type> > >(std::move(copy), tokens); 
}

int main()
{
  auto v = StringToVector(std::string("hello world"), " ");
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/LEqnww)

Comment: It would be but for the fact the the user wants thew entire string added to the vector, Not the elements of the string.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377080/how-to-overcome-the-msvc-bug-of-failing-deduction-of-template-argument-of-pointe/58378108#comment103104558_58377080

Comment: @NathanOliver I see the point, I guess then it's even simpler

Answer (score 0):

#### Workaround 1

Make the problematic parameter as the first type of the template and pass it explicitly.

```
template<typename Parameter,
         typename Return,
         typename Container>
Container
StringTo (Parameter&& copy,
          const char tokens[],
          Return (Container::*Insert) (const Parameter&))
{
  Container container;
  // do something ...
  return container;
}

template<typename Type>
auto
StringToVector (Type&& copy,
                const char tokens[])
{
  return StringTo<Type>(std::move(copy), tokens, &std::vector<Type>::push_back);
} //             ^^^^^^ here (explicit)                       ^^^^ passed anyways
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/ZYFFNS61678)

---

#### Workaround 2

If we compromise on the `Type` part and use directly `std::string`, then this error goes away in MSVC as well.

```
template<typename Return,
         typename Container>
Container
StringTo (std::string&& copy, // Type --> std::string
          const char tokens[],
          Return (Container::*Insert) (const std::string&))
{
  Container container;
  // do something ...
  return container;
}

inline
auto
StringToVector (std::string&& copy,
                const char tokens[])
{
  return StringTo(std::move(copy), tokens, &std::vector<std::string>::push_back);
}
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/KXMRG30860).